# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null - Twitter Post Fetcher

Tags: jquery

I'm using [Twitter Post Fetcher](https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher) and I am getting an error on page load:-

Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null.

I've tried wrapping this with:-

```
window.onload = function() {
    // all of your code goes in here
    // it runs after the DOM is built
}
```

But then I get this error:-

Uncaught ReferenceError: twitterFetcher is not defined

And the Tweets no longer get pulled. I've also tried calling the JavaScript in the footer as opposed to the header but I still have the same issue. Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Here is the main code from Twitter Post Fetcher:-

```
window.onload = function() {
(function(C,p){"function"===typeof define&&define.amd?define([],p):"object"===typeof exports?module.exports=p():p()})(this,function(){function C(a){if(null===r){for(var g=a.length,c=0,k=document.getElementById(D),f="<ul>";c<g;)f+="<li>"+a[c]+"</li>",c++;k.innerHTML=f+"</ul>"}else r(a)}function p(a){return a.replace(/<b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/b>/gi,function(a,c){return c}).replace(/class="(?!(tco-hidden|tco-display|tco-ellipsis))+.*?"|data-query-source=".*?"|dir=".*?"|rel=".*?"/gi,"")}function E(a){a=a.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var g=a.length-1;0<=g;g--)a[g].setAttribute("target","_blank")}function l(a,g){for(var c=[],k=new RegExp("(^| )"+g+"( |$)"),f=a.getElementsByTagName("*"),h=0,b=f.length;h<b;h++)k.test(f[h].className)&&c.push(f[h]);return c}function F(a){if(void 0!==a&&0<=a.innerHTML.indexOf("data-srcset"))return a=a.innerHTML.match(/data-srcset="([A-z0-9%_\.-]+)/i)[0],decodeURIComponent(a).split('"')[1]}var D="",g=20,G=!0,v=[],x=!1,y=!0,w=!0,z=null,A=!0,B=!0,r=null,H=!0,I=!1,t=!0,J=!0,K=!1,m=null,L={fetch:function(a){void 0===
a.maxTweets&&(a.maxTweets=20);void 0===a.enableLinks&&(a.enableLinks=!0);void 0===a.showUser&&(a.showUser=!0);void 0===a.showTime&&(a.showTime=!0);void 0===a.dateFunction&&(a.dateFunction="default");void 0===a.showRetweet&&(a.showRetweet=!0);void 0===a.customCallback&&(a.customCallback=null);void 0===a.showInteraction&&(a.showInteraction=!0);void 0===a.showImages&&(a.showImages=!1);void 0===a.linksInNewWindow&&(a.linksInNewWindow=!0);void 0===a.showPermalinks&&(a.showPermalinks=!0);void 0===a.dataOnly&&
(a.dataOnly=!1);if(x)v.push(a);else{x=!0;D=a.domId;g=a.maxTweets;G=a.enableLinks;w=a.showUser;y=a.showTime;B=a.showRetweet;z=a.dateFunction;r=a.customCallback;H=a.showInteraction;I=a.showImages;t=a.linksInNewWindow;J=a.showPermalinks;K=a.dataOnly;var l=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];null!==m&&l.removeChild(m);m=document.createElement("script");m.type="text/javascript";m.src="https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/timelines/"+a.id+"?&lang="+(a.lang||"en")+"&callback=twitterFetcher.callback&suppress_response_codes=true&rnd="+
Math.random();l.appendChild(m)}},callback:function(a){function m(a){var b=a.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];b.src=b.getAttribute("data-src-2x");return a}var c=document.createElement("div");c.innerHTML=a.body;"undefined"===typeof c.getElementsByClassName&&(A=!1);a=[];var k=[],f=[],h=[],b=[],q=[],n=[],e=0;if(A)for(c=c.getElementsByClassName("timeline-Tweet");e<c.length;){0<c[e].getElementsByClassName("timeline-Tweet-retweetCredit").length?b.push(!0):b.push(!1);if(!b[e]||b[e]&&B)a.push(c[e].getElementsByClassName("timeline-Tweet-text")[0]),
q.push(c[e].getAttribute("data-tweet-id")),k.push(m(c[e].getElementsByClassName("timeline-Tweet-author")[0])),f.push(c[e].getElementsByClassName("dt-updated")[0]),n.push(c[e].getElementsByClassName("timeline-Tweet-timestamp")[0]),void 0!==c[e].getElementsByClassName("timeline-Tweet-media")[0]?h.push(c[e].getElementsByClassName("timeline-Tweet-media")[0]):h.push(void 0);e++}else for(c=l(c,"timeline-Tweet");e<c.length;){0<l(c[e],"timeline-Tweet-retweetCredit").length?b.push(!0):b.push(!1);if(!b[e]||
b[e]&&B)a.push(l(c[e],"timeline-Tweet-text")[0]),q.push(c[e].getAttribute("data-tweet-id")),k.push(m(l(c[e],"timeline-Tweet-author")[0])),f.push(l(c[e],"dt-updated")[0]),n.push(l(c[e],"timeline-Tweet-timestamp")[0]),void 0!==l(c[e],"timeline-Tweet-media")[0]?h.push(l(c[e],"timeline-Tweet-media")[0]):h.push(void 0);e++}a.length>g&&(a.splice(g,a.length-g),k.splice(g,k.length-g),f.splice(g,f.length-g),b.splice(g,b.length-g),h.splice(g,h.length-g),n.splice(g,n.length-g));var c=[],e=a.length,d=0;if(K)for(;d<
e;)c.push({tweet:a[d].innerHTML,author:k[d].innerHTML,time:f[d].textContent,image:F(h[d]),rt:b[d],tid:q[d],permalinkURL:void 0===n[d]?"":n[d].href}),d++;else for(;d<e;){if("string"!==typeof z){var b=f[d].getAttribute("datetime"),u=new Date(f[d].getAttribute("datetime").replace(/-/g,"/").replace("T"," ").split("+")[0]),b=z(u,b);f[d].setAttribute("aria-label",b);if(a[d].textContent)if(A)f[d].textContent=b;else{var u=document.createElement("p"),r=document.createTextNode(b);u.appendChild(r);u.setAttribute("aria-label",
b);f[d]=u}else f[d].textContent=b}b="";G?(t&&(E(a[d]),w&&E(k[d])),w&&(b+='<div class="user">'+p(k[d].innerHTML)+"</div>"),b+='<p class="tweet">'+p(a[d].innerHTML)+"</p>",y&&(b=J?b+('<p class="timePosted"><a href="'+n[d]+'">'+f[d].getAttribute("aria-label")+"</a></p>"):b+('<p class="timePosted">'+f[d].getAttribute("aria-label")+"</p>"))):(w&&(b+='<p class="user">'+k[d].textContent+"</p>"),b+='<p class="tweet">'+a[d].textContent+"</p>",y&&(b+='<p class="timePosted">'+f[d].textContent+"</p>"));H&&(b+=
'<p class="interact"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to='+q[d]+'" class="twitter_reply_icon"'+(t?' target="_blank">':">")+'Reply</a><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id='+q[d]+'" class="twitter_retweet_icon"'+(t?' target="_blank">':">")+'Retweet</a><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id='+q[d]+'" class="twitter_fav_icon"'+(t?' target="_blank">':">")+"Favorite</a></p>");I&&void 0!==h[d]&&(b+='<div class="media"><img src="'+F(h[d])+'" alt="Image from tweet" /></div>');
c.push(b);d++}C(c);x=!1;0<v.length&&(L.fetch(v[0]),v.splice(0,1))}};return window.twitterFetcher=L});
}
```

Comment: It would be more helpfuf to post your relevant code instead of the minified plugin code... I would more expect a bug in your code than in the plugin...

Comment: You should also try moving the plugin code to a different file. For plugins, you generally want to load them in a separate file before running your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the creator of the Twitter Fetcher.

First of all please make sure you are using the latest version from GitHub. There was a recent update due to a change in Twitter:

https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher

Next include the code for the Twitter Fetcher before you write any other JavaScript that attempts to use it, ideally in the `head` of the document. The minified code can be found here:

https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher/blob/master/js/twitterFetcher_min.js

Finally, the DOM element into which you wish to inject the tweets must exist before the JS calling Twitter Fetcher is executed. You can do this in one of two ways:

1. Place all javascript imports related to calling the twitterFetcher just before the closing `</body>` tag.
2. Programatically in JavaScript wait for the DOM to load and then execute your code to call the Twitter Fetcher.

Finally use the examples as shown here to use the Twitter Fetcher:

https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher/blob/master/js/exampleUsage.js

A simple example is as follows to fetch your most recent 5 tweets:

```
// ##### Simple example 1 #####
// A simple example to get my latest tweet and write to a HTML element with
// id "example1". Also automatically hyperlinks URLS and user mentions and
// hashtags.
var config1 = {
  "id": '{{YOUR TWITTER WIDGET ID HERE}}',
  "domId": '{{YOUR ID OF THE ELEMENT YOU WANT TO INJECT INTO HERE}}',
  "maxTweets": 5,
  "enableLinks": true
};
twitterFetcher.fetch(config1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused for us by the "id" being wrong (and using older version) (i.e. we don't do twitter)

We used the method (example1):

```
"profile": {
  "screenName": 'ID_twit'
},
```

Also REMEMBER to either disable/comment-out the examples or edit the examples so that you really DO HAVE a DOM object as per the examples.